# TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

Above are all the scripts 
and below them is the jquery autocomplete: all this simply does is is show an autocomplete from an input tag. I've tried re-arranging the script tags, adding different versions of jquery nothing seems to work

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];
    $("#d").autocomplete({
      source: aTags
    });

  });
</script>

<input id="d" type="text" />
```

Comment: Creating a snippet and hence a [mcve] for you shows it works here - maybe because you did not include ALL the scripts here, EVEN when I add modernizer it works

Comment: The code is fine. The only thing to mention - you have to put your scripts into head tag to execute each one synchronously.

Comment: code snippet is working fine.

Comment: @Artem it is already in head tags I never included the tags in this question

Comment: @MarkEvans `console.log($("#d"))` may be the problem is here

Comment: @NawedKhan So why am I still getting the error?

Comment: @MarkEvans check what is `$("#d")` at the moment it fails. The problem must be there

Comment: Destination:<input type="text" id="d" />
    Leaving From<input type="text" id="l" />

Comment: seems to be a visual studio/MVC problem this is why I prefer to write things in pure JavaScript but I just haven't got the time. i